# wx.ProgressDialog too small

Tags: python, wxpython

My program uses [`wx.ProgressDialog`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ProgressDialog-class.html) to give feedback on a process that is in multiple stages.  At the beginning of each stage, I use the second argument of `Update` to change the message in the dialog.

The problem is that the width of the dialog is determined from the message in the constructor, and the dialog is not resized if a later call to `Update` sets the message to something longer.

Apart from giving a long message in the constructor, is there a way to make the dialog bigger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

call wx.Fit() on the dialog, or you can use SetSize((x, y))